# Extracting required substring from a result retrieved from Wolfram Alpha with Java

Tags: java, regex, wolframalpha

I'm working on a Java Program which takes a question from a user, sends it to the Wolfram Alpha API and then cleans up the result and prints it.

If the user asks the question "Who is the President of the USA?" the result is as follows

```
Response: <section><title>Input interpretation</title>    <sectioncontents>United States | President</sectioncontents></section><section><title>Result</title><sectioncontents>Barack Obama  (from 20/01/2009  to  present)</sectioncontents></section><section><title>Basic information</title><sectioncontents>official position | President (44th)..........etc
```

I would like to Extract "Barack Obama (from 20/01/2009 to present)"

I have been able to trim up to Barack using the below code:

```
String clean =response.substring(response.indexOf("Result") + 31 , response.length());
    System.out.println("Response: " + clean);
```

How would I trim the rest of the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in case it helps, I came up with this regex:

```
Result.+?>([^<]+?)<
```

After finding "Result" it captures the first instance of > and < with at least one character between them.

**UPDATE**
Below is some sample code that might be helpful:

```
String response = "Response: <section><title>..."
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Result.+?>([^<]+?)<");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(response);
String clean = "";
if (match.find())
    clean = match.group(1);
System.out.println(clean);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, but how would you actually apply this regex to my code? I'm struggling to understand the logic.

Comment: @JEarls added some sample code that might help. Beyond that I'd recommmend reading

Comment: ...sorry... reading the methods of the pattern and matcher classes at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: This code worked did exactly what I wanted it to. Thank you @shrug

Answer (score 0):

The response is essentially XML.

As has been discussed endlessly in many programming fora, regular expressions are not suitable for parsing XML - you should use an XML parser.